# Using DATASet Api with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am very new to spark/Scala and trying to implement some functionality.My requirement is very simple.I have to perform all the the operations using DataSet API.

**Question1:**
I converted the csv in form a case Class?Is it correct way of converting data frame to DataSet??Am I doing it correctly?

Also when I am trying to do transformation on **orderItemFile1**,for  filter/map operation I am able to access with _.order_id.But same is not happening with groupBy

```
 case class  orderItemDetails (order_id_order_item:Int, item_desc:String,qty:Int,   sale_value:Int)
    val orderItemFile1=ss.read.format("csv")
        .option("header",true)
        .option("infersSchema",true)
        .load("src/main/resources/Order_ItemData.csv").as[orderItemDetails]

         orderItemFile1.filter(_.order_id_order_item>100) //Works Fine
         orderItemFile1.map(_.order_id_order_item.toInt)// Works Fine

//Error .Inside group By I am unable to  access it as _.order_id_order_item. Why So?
   orderItemFile1.groupBy(_.order_id_order_item) 

//Below Works..But How this will provide compile time safely as committed 
//by DataSet Api.I can pass any wrong column name also here and it will be //caught only on run time

orderItemFile1.groupBy(orderItemFile1("order_id_order_item")).agg(sum(orderItemFile1("item_desc")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the functionality you're looking for is `#groupByKey`. See example [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-basic-aggregation.html#groupByKey).

As for your first question, basically yes, you're reading a CSV into a `Dataset[A]` where `A` is a case class you've declared.